# read data in mysql from android : ERROR : String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I want to read data in my db and then display it in the emulator, for that i am using a php script as a web service to connect to my Mysql db, but my program throw me an exception in the parsing of Json, this the exception :

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I did some research on the internet but I only found this problem anywhere without the solution

Please if anyone can help me, I really need that 
This my code :

```
  <?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
  mysql_select_db("bdVille");
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblVille where Nom_ville like'".$_REQUEST['ville']."%'");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  $output[]=$row;
  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close();
  ?>
```

and this is the java code :

```
package com.exemple.ville;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ville extends Activity {
TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());  
    txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
    rootLayout.addView(txt);  
    setContentView(rootLayout);  

    // D√©finir le texte et appeler la fonction de connexion.  
    txt.setText("Connexion..."); 
    // Appeler la m√©thode pour r√©cup√©rer les donn√©es JSON
    txt.setText(getServerData(strURL)); 
}

// Mettre l'adresse du script PHP
// Attention localhost ou 127.0.0.1 ne fonctionnent pas. Mettre l'adresse IP local.
public static final String strURL = "http://192.168.1.108/htdocs/ville.php";

private String getServerData(String returnString) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    // Envoyer la requ√™te au script PHP.
    // Script PHP : $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblVille where Nom_ville like '".$_REQUEST['ville']."%'");
    // $_REQUEST['ville'] sera remplac√© par L dans notre exemple.
    // Ce qui veut dire que la requ√™te enverra les villes commen√ßant par la lettre L
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ville","L"));

    // Envoie de la commande http
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // Convertion de la requ√™te en string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // Parse les donn√©es JSON
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // Affichage ID_ville et Nom_ville dans le LogCat
            Log.i("log_tag","ID_ville: "+json_data.getInt("ID_ville")+", Nom_ville: "+json_data.getString("Nom_ville"));
            Toast.makeText(this, "ID_ville: "+json_data.getInt("ID_ville")+", Nom_ville: "+json_data.getString("Nom_ville"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // R√©sultats de la requ√™te
            returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return returnString; 
}
```

}

Comment: Your execption has nothing to do with the web service. This exception is thrown before the return statement. You should proceed to a step-by-step debug in your loop until you find which routine is causing the problem.

Comment: The error is caused by this line: JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result); but I don't know how i fix it

Comment: Can you give us the value of the "result" string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it seems that your json encoding it;s not working correctly, actually on the JSON you gave:

```
[
    {
        "ID_ville": "1",
        "Nom_ville": "Paris"
    },
    {
        "ID_ville": "2",
        "Nom_ville": "Marseille"
    },
    {
        "‌​ID_ville": "3",
        "Nom_ville": "Lyon"
    },
    {
        "ID_ville": "4",
        "Nom_ville": "Toulouse"
    },
    {
        "ID_vi‌​lle": "5",
        "Nom_ville": "Nice"
    },
    {
        "ID_ville": "6",
        "Nom_ville": "Nantes"
    },
    {
        "ID_ville": "7"‌​,
        "Nom_ville": "Strasbourg"
    },
    {
        "ID_ville": "8",
        "Nom_ville": "Montpellier"
    },
    {
        "ID_ville"‌​: "9",
        "Nom_ville": "Bordeaux"
    },
    {
        "ID_ville": "10",
        "Nom_ville": "Lille"
    }
]
```

Try putting that in jsonlint.com and will give you the error, the problem it's that there it's a [ZERO WIDTH JOINER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) character, probably you might want to start just echo a static json to check this. My Guess, is that you  someway somehow copy-paste this character.

**Another way to test this character is there?**, try Copy-paste this {"ID_ville"‌​:"9","Nom_ville":"Bordeaux"}, in the console you'll see something like this

[image]

**Solution**

Check you're character, encoding and try the response with a static echo instead of going to the Database.

Comment: Hi again, I m back! I still have the same problem. Actually, I removed, from the test database, the two lines that cause the problem in JsonLITE.com(thanks for the URL) and then I tried the new string  in this site and it did not give any error, but in my program, I still have the same error !!

Comment: Can you Log.d("RESULT", result) before you do the jsonArray? and post that result. You are probably not refering the correct url, or passing the wrong parameter, let know.

Comment: here, just the value of result to be more clear and easy to read : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /ville.php was not found on this server.</p><hr> <address>Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) DAV/2 Server at 192.168.1.144 Port 80</address>  </body></html>

Comment: It works! thanks a lot for ur help, I realized that I had to add the port in the server address like that : http://00.00.00.00:8888/script.php. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Hey make these changes.

```
package com.Online.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OnlineTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView resultView;
    HttpClient client;
    JSONObject json;
    String Dat;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvjson);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            json = RedData();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      Dat = json.toString();

        new Read().onPostExecute(Dat);
    }
    public JSONObject RedData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("//link.php");     
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(httppost);

       // int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        //if (status == 200) {

            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject last = jArray.getJSONObject(0); // 0 -> the last object
            return last;

       // } else {
         //   Toast.makeText(OnlineTestActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          //  return null;
        //}
    }


    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                json = RedData();
                //Toast.makeText(OnlineTestActivity.this, json.getString(arg0[0]), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                return json.getString(arg0[0]);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            resultView.setText(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error comes from that line :

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

You are trying to convert a non-valid Json string into a json array.

Comment: As I said before, give us the "result" content. We can see if the string is valid or not.

Comment: in the the browser (http://localhost:8888/ville.php), i have this result : [{"ID_ville":"1","Nom_ville":"Paris"},{"ID_ville":"2","Nom_ville":"Marseille"},{"ID_ville":"3","Nom_ville":"Lyon"},{"ID_ville":"4","Nom_ville":"Toulouse"},{"ID_ville":"5","Nom_ville":"Nice"},{"ID_ville":"6","Nom_ville":"Nantes"},{"ID_ville":"7","Nom_ville":"Strasbourg"},{"ID_ville":"8","Nom_ville":"Montpellier"},{"ID_ville":"9","Nom_ville":"Bordeaux"},{"ID_ville":"10","Nom_ville":"Lille"}]